# Can You Create Singletons With MVVM in SwiftUI

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, mvvm, swiftui

I am working on a SwiftUI project and attempting to use MVVM. I am using Firebase as a backend and recently introduced rules on my Firestore database and am having a lot of trouble which I believe is related to my implementation of MVVM.

I followed a tutorial from Google on MVVM and I believe the larger project I am working on is causing issues. Here is a base case for how I'm using MVVM.

**Repository Files**
These files are being used connect to Firestore. Here is a UserRepository example.

```
class ListingRepository: ObservableObject {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    private var snapshotListener: ListenerRegistration?
    
    @Published var listings = [Listing]()
    
    init() {
        startSnapshotListener()
    }
        
    func startSnapshotListener() {
        if snapshotListener == nil {
            self.snapshotListener = db.collection(FirestoreCollection.listings).order(by: "created", descending: true).addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(error)")
                } else {
                    guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                        print("No Listings.")
                        return
                    }
                    
                    // Documents exist.
                    self.listings = documents.compactMap { listing in
                        do {
                            return try listing.data(as: Listing.self)
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                        return nil
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    func stopSnapshotListener() {
        if snapshotListener != nil {
            snapshotListener?.remove()
            snapshotListener = nil
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel and @main**
In the app. Listings are a part of a Marketplace. I am making my ViewModel the @EnvironmentObject. In @main I have the following. I am initializing an instance of ListingRepository here.

```
@main
struct ExchangeApp: App {
    
    // @EnvironmentObjects
    @StateObject private var marketplaceViewModel = MarketplaceViewModel(listingRepository: ListingRepository())
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(marketplaceViewModel)
        }
    }
}
```

**MarketplaceViewModel**

```
class MarketplaceViewModel: ObservableObject {

    var listingRepository: ListingRepository
    
    @Published var listingRowViewModels = [ListingRowViewModel]()
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
        
    init(listingRepository: ListingRepository) {
        self.listingRepository = listingRepository
        self.startCombine()
    }
    
    func startCombine() {
        listingRepository
            .$listings
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .map { listings in
                listings
                    .map { listing in
                    ListingRowViewModel(listing: listing)
                }
            }
            .assign(to: \.listingRowViewModels, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

**MarketplaceView**
In MarketplaceView I take each listing and present it. There are other files here that are not shown but I don't believe this is important to the question. I am happy to provide more if needed.

```
struct MarketplaceView: View {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    @EnvironmentObject var authSession: AuthSession
    @EnvironmentObject var marketplaceViewModel: MarketplaceViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(self.marketplaceViewModel.filteredListingRowViewModels, id: \.id) { listingRowViewModel in
                    NavigationLink(destination: ListingDetailView(listingDetailViewModel: ListingDetailViewModel(listing: listingRowViewModel.listing, userRepository: UserRepository()))
                                    .environmentObject(authSession)
                    ) {
                        ListingRowView(listingRowViewModel: listingRowViewModel)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Marketplace")
        }
    }
}
```

While this works really well, I am not sure its expands to a larger app well. I have a lot of Repository files and view models which means my @main ends up looking like the following.

**@main**

```
@main
struct Global_Seafood_ExchangeApp: App {
        
    @StateObject private var authListener = AuthSession(userRepository: UserRepository(), productRepository: ProductRepository(), listingRepository: ListingRepository(), offerRepository: OfferRepository(), orderRepository: OrderRepository(), businessAddressRepository: BusinessAddressRepository(), bankAccountRepository: BankAccountRepository())
    @StateObject private var marketplaceViewModel = MarketplaceViewModel(listingRepository: ListingRepository())
    @StateObject private var createListingViewModel = CreateListingViewModel(listingRepository: ListingRepository(), productRepository: SeafoodRepository())
    @StateObject private var accountViewModel = AccountViewModel(listingRepository: ListingRepository(), offerRepository: OfferRepository(), orderRepository: OrderRepository())
    @StateObject private var addBusinessViewModel = AddBusinessAddressViewModel(businessAddressRepository: BusinessAddressRepository())
    @StateObject private var addBankAccountViewModel = AddBankAccountViewModel(bankAccountRepository: BankAccountRepository())
    @StateObject private var listingHistoryViewModel = ListingHistoryViewModel(listingRepository: ListingRepository())
    @StateObject private var offerHistoryViewModel = OfferHistoryViewModel(offerRepository: OfferRepository())
    @StateObject private var orderHistoryViewModel = OrderHistoryViewModel(orderRepository: OrderRepository())
    @StateObject private var businessAddressViewModel = BusinessAddressViewModel(businessAddressRepository: BusinessAddressRepository())
    @StateObject private var bankAccountViewModel = BankAccountViewModel(bankAccountRepository: BankAccountRepository())
        
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(authListener)
                .environmentObject(marketplaceViewModel)
                .environmentObject(createListingViewModel)
                .environmentObject(accountViewModel)
                .environmentObject(addBusinessViewModel)
                .environmentObject(addBankAccountViewModel)
                .environmentObject(listingHistoryViewModel)
                .environmentObject(offerHistoryViewModel)
                .environmentObject(orderHistoryViewModel)
                .environmentObject(businessAddressViewModel)
                .environmentObject(bankAccountViewModel)
        }
    }
}
```

You can see here that Repositories are initialized multiple times. I don't think this is a good idea.

My issue really started when I added Firestore rules to my database. I am requiring someone to be authenticated to view data from the repositories. When someone logs in, I make a call to start all of the repositories and set up the Snapshot Listeners, and then when someone logs out I make a call to stop all of the Snapshot Listeners. However, even after stopping them, multiple are still running which I believe is due to the fact that I've initialized more than one in @main. I have confirmed this since I get permission request errors from Firestore letting me know the listeners are returning errors since the user is not authenticated.

**Singletons**
I looked into using Singletons but this seems to be a bad design choice.

**StateObject**
I looked at using the Repositories as StateObjects but this creates UI update issues.

My two questions.

1. Can someone confirm my issues is that I am instantiating multiple instances of Repositories?
2. What MVVM practice is best for an app this size? I understand this is a loaded question but I've read a number of tutorials and all seem to say they are a good idea. However, in practice I am running into issues with the ones I've tried.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you are creating multiple instances. You can make a singleton by simply using `static let shared = Firestore.firestore()` in your model class.

Comment: @Yrb By model class do you mean in the repository? My model file is not shown here.

Comment: Hey @jonthornham - Firebaser here. Which tutorial are you referring to? When using a repository approach, I recommend using dependency injection (my favourite is Resolver) to ensure you have only one instance of each repo and service (most importantly your Auth service).

Comment: TL;DR; - be more focused and provide simple demo.

Comment: @PeterFriese thank you for this. I’ve been reading about resolver and will start implementing it Monday. Looks like a great solution.

Comment: @jonthornham if you find Peter Friese's comment useful, kindly post it as an answer. The community will find this very helpful.

Comment: @RobertG I am traveling back from the holiday and will confirm this works. Once confirmed I will mark it as the acceptable answer. I have a considerable task to rewrite the app to verify this. I will get back though.

Comment: @PeterFriese This is definitely the answer. I've ben rewriting the app and things are working out. Once cleaned up I'll post a detailed answer. As always, thanks for the guidance. I'm puzzled as to why Resolver is not part of the iOS SDK.

Comment: Seems like there is appetite for a dependency injection tutorial?

Comment: @PeterFriese I would say this would be a great topic. Your current posts are great but a more detailed post with the new InjectedObject would be great.